# Get input.value in loop

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JS, and a little confused)
I'm trying to select all elements in page by className, find in them input that have `type=hidden`, and take value of inputs to  variable.

To be more clear I'll show demo html.

```
<div class="demo_class">
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <input type="hidden" value="some-value">
</div>
<div class="demo_class">
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <input type="hidden" value="some-value">
</div>
<div class="demo_class">
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <input type="hidden" value="some-value">
</div>
<div class="demo_class">
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <input type="hidden" value="some-value">
</div>
```

And there is some JavaScript

```
var container = document.getElementsByClassName("demo_class");
for (var i = 0; i < container.length; i++) {
    var inputValue = container[i].querySelectorAll("input[type=hidden]");
    container[i].insertAdjacentHTML(
        'afterbegin', 
        '<a href ="' + inputValue + '">Some text</a>'
   );
}
```

in this code I find all `demo_class`, in each of them find `input[type=hidden]`, but I cant do nothing with there value.. with code

`inputValue.value` there is undefined. Why? What I doing wrong?

I no need jQuery, want to learn JavaScript.

Comment: Use closure inside `for` to persist the value of `i`.

Comment: What's the difference I do it from the console devtools or directly write in code?

Comment: @CroaToa Try this code, `var container = document.getElementsByClassName("demo_class");

for(var i = 0; i < container.length; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        var inputValue = container[i].querySelectorAll("input[type=hidden]");
        container[i].insertAdjacentHTML(
            'afterbegin',
            '<a href ="' + inputValue + '">Some text</a>'
        );
    }(i));
}`, let me know if this work for you.

Comment: Working partial ) In href not value. In href `[object NodeList]`

Comment: @CroaToa Your original [code works](http://jsfiddle.net/vcg4b9p6/1/) with a small change. As Adi has answered, you're not getting the value of input.

Comment: But tell me please, why in JSFiddle code works, but when I try to do that from console in this page for example (see my comment under Adi answer) it dont work?

Comment: because jsFiddle runs the code withing iframe which listen to differen console

Comment: But I dont run code in JSFiddle, I run it here, here is not iframe. Just run this code here, open devtools and run in console `var container = document.getElementsByClassName("js-gps-track"); for (var i = 0; i < container.length; i++) { var inputValue = container[i].querySelectorAll("div")[0].innerText; container[i].insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterbegin', '<a href ="' + inputValue + '">Some text</a>' ); }` This code must choose all divs with className `js-gps-track`, find into them `div`, get it text and append it into new element `a`

Answer (score 1):

you don't get the value, but the element it self.

replace

```
var inputValue =   container[i].querySelectorAll("input[type=hidden]");
```

with

```
var inputValue =   container[i].querySelectorAll("input[type=hidden]")[0].value;
```

> **querySelectorAll()** - Returs array of results (event if it find one element)
>
> **.value** - Property to set/retrive the value of specific element

See here working example - [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uL8m3xhn/)

Comment: There is already undefined..  console write  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined(…)

Comment: strangely.. For example open devtools to this page, there is a few blocks with class `js-gps-track`  and try to get `answer-votes` text..  Its look like `var container = document.getElementsByClassName("js-gps-track");
for (var i = 0; i < container.length; i++) {
    var inputValue =   container[i].querySelectorAll("div")[0].innerText;
container[i].insertAdjacentHTML(
    'afterbegin', 
    '<a href ="' + inputValue + '">Some text</a>'
   );
}` and you got error `Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined`  I mean, do that in console

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem depends on the DOMContentLoaded event, which isn't already fired when you exec your code...

```js
function ExampleCtrl() {
  'use strict';
  var self = this;
  
  self.hiddenInputs = document.querySelectorAll('[type="hidden"]');
  self.result = document.getElementById('result');
  
  for(var input, tpl, i = 0, len = self.hiddenInputs.length; i < len; i++) {
    input = self.hiddenInputs[i];
    tpl = '<span class="key">'+ (i + 1) +'</span><span class="value">'+ input.value +'</span>';
    
    self.result.innerHTML += '<h1>'+ tpl +'</h1>';  
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ExampleCtrl);
```

```css
#result {
  padding: 1em .5em;
}

#result .key { 
  font-weight: bolder;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 2em;
}
#result .value {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo_class">
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <input type="hidden" value="some-value">
</div>
<div class="demo_class">
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <input type="hidden" value="some-value">
</div>
<div class="demo_class">
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <input type="hidden" value="some-value">
</div>
<div class="demo_class">
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <input type="hidden" value="some-value">
</div>

<div id="result">
  
</div>
```